# How to get SQL query result column name as first row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, dynamicquery

I have a dynamic SQL query that gets me result sets after execution. However, the UI model that I am rendering results back from SQL server engine doesn't provide a way to render query column names.

Due to the dynamic nature of the query, I can't hard code the column names at design time. So my question is how do I get column names along with the data set returned by the query?

This Query:

```
DECLARE @SQLSTATMENT nvarchar(1000) 
SELECT @SQLSTATEMENT = ' 
                            SELECT 
                                convert(date, DATEADDED) DATEADDED
                                ,COUNT(1) as NUMBEROFRECORDS
                            FROM 
                                dbo.CONSTITUENT 
                            GROUP BY 
                                convert(date, DATEADDED)
                            ORDER BY 
                                convert(date, DATEADDED) DESC
                                '
            Exec (@SQLSTATEMENT);
```

Gives me this table ([Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gfTI.png)):

```
+ ---------- + --------------- +
| DATEADDED  | NUMBEROFRECORDS |
+ ---------- + --------------- +
| 2017-03-14 | 1               |
| 2017-03-10 | 1               |
| 2016-07-07 | 5               |
| 2016-06-29 | 3               |
| 2016-06-15 | 1               |
| 2014-11-11 | 465             |
| 2005-06-09 | 11              |
| 2005-04-13 | 1               |
| 2005-02-28 | 2               |
+ ---------- + --------------- +
```

But I want this ([Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WuUM.png)):

```
+ ---------- + --------------- +
| DATEADDED  | NUMBEROFRECORDS |
+ ---------- + --------------- +
| DATEADDED  | NUMBEROFRECORDS |
| 2017-03-14 | 1               |
| 2017-03-10 | 1               |
| 2016-07-07 | 5               |
| 2016-06-29 | 3               |
| 2016-06-15 | 1               |
| 2014-11-11 | 465             |
| 2005-06-09 | 11              |
| 2005-04-13 | 1               |
| 2005-02-28 | 2               |
+ ---------- + --------------- +
```

Thanks

Comment: Huh??? The column names are right there....as the names of the columns. If your front end can't determine the column headers from the column names that is an issue. But what are you expecting as output? And why are using dynamic sql here in the first place? There is nothing posted here that suggests you need dynamic sql.

Comment: I think that his/her wishes are just to do as Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio do: Putting some request in and getting a result inside a "datagridview" with all the column names not set in advance.

Comment: Yes, I have attached the expected output for the query I have in the first screen capture.

Comment: Sean, The query is piece of customization on CRM application hosted on the cloud. The CRM has it own query tool but limited to certain native tables. When you have custom and other tables generated due to different processes, you can't directly query them and that is the need for Dynamic SQL. I hope this make sense.

Answer (score 2):

It's doable, but not very pretty.  A Stored Procedure where you pass the dynamic SQL would be much cleaner

We're essentially doing Dynamic SQL within Dynamic SQL

One caveat:  I reserved the field RN

**Example (Using my FRED Series Data)**

```
-- This is Your Base/Initial Query, or the only portion you need to supply
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = 'Select Updated  as Updated,Count(*) as NumberOfRecords From [dbo].[FRED-Series] Group By Updated'

Select @SQL = '
;with cte0 as ('+@SQL+')
    , cte1 as (Select *,RN = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null)) From cte0 ) 
    , cte2 as (
        Select A.RN,C.*
         From  cte1 A
         Cross Apply (Select XMLData=cast((Select A.* for XML Raw) as xml)) B
         Cross Apply (
                        Select Item   = attr.value(''local-name(.)'',''varchar(100)'')
                              ,Value  = attr.value(''.'',''varchar(max)'') 
                              ,ColNr  = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select Null))
                         From  B.XMLData.nodes(''/row'') as A(r)
                         Cross Apply A.r.nodes(''./@*'') AS B(attr)
                         Where attr.value(''local-name(.)'',''varchar(100)'') not in (''RN'')
                     ) C
      )
Select Distinct RN=0,Item,Value=Item,ColNr Into #Temp From cte2 Union All Select * from cte2

Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select '','' + QuoteName(Item) From #Temp Where RN=0 Order by ColNr For XML Path('''')),1,1,'''') 
Select  @SQL = ''Select '' + @SQL + '' From (Select RN,Item,Value From #Temp ) A Pivot (max(Value) For [Item] in ('' + @SQL + '') ) p''
Exec(@SQL);
'
Exec(@SQL)
```

**Returns**

```
Updated     NumberOfRecords
Updated     NumberOfRecords
2017-03-22  597
2017-03-23  40
2017-03-20  228
2017-03-21  1404
```

**Just some Commentary**

cte0 is your primary query

cte1 will take the results of your initial query and add a Row Number

cte2 will dynamically unpivot your data

The results of cte2 are dropped into a #temp table for convenience (assuming this is allowed)

Then we perform a dynamic pivot

Answer (score 0):

Union a static query with the column names. You have to cast the results of the second query to varchar or nvarchar so they are the same data type as your column names.

```
DECLARE @SQLSTATMENT nvarchar(1000) 
SELECT @SQLSTATEMENT = ' 
    SELECT
        ''DATEADDED'' AS [DATEADDED]
        ,''NUMBEROFRECORDS'' AS [NUMBEROFRECORDS]

    SELECT 
        CAST(convert(date, DATEADDED) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,CAST(COUNT(1) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM 
        dbo.CONSTITUENT 
    GROUP BY 
        convert(date, DATEADDED)
    ORDER BY 
        convert(date, DATEADDED) DESC
'
Exec (@SQLSTATEMENT);
```

With this said, you should be able to reference the column names via code and not have to add them to the query. This way you could keep the data types of the result set.

Comment: This is not what I wanted. I don't want hard coding column names as I can't do that at run time. I need a dynamic way to pick up column names from the same query executed and make it the names part of the data set. Think of a database over 100K tables and views that users come up with many combinations of queries.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are looking for. You're dynamic query is the correct way to pick up tables dynamically. How are you determining what tables to query? If they are passed as a variable then you can parameterize the query.